# Android: Image over OpenGL-ES Game (HUD)

Tags: java, android, opengl-es

I made a basic 3D Game for Android and want to add a HUD. How should I do this? Is it possible to add a layout which stays on top of the 3D game or I have to do this with OpenGL?

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to add one or several layouts over the openGL layout. To do this you have to start with a RelativeLayout. It will contain both OpenGL and Hud Layout. The declaration order is important (first declared, first rendered). To change the position of your Hud layout, you can use the layout_margin attributes, or use match_parent if it is a full overlay.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <!-- START of OpenGL Layout -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/openGLLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp" >
    </LinearLayout>
    <!-- END of OpenGL Layout -->

    <!-- START of HUD Layout -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/hudLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp">
        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/hudText"
            android:text="Hud Text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        </TextView>
    </LinearLayout>
    <!-- END of HUD Layout -->

</RelativeLayout>
```

In this example, the OpenGL layout is an empy LinearLayout used as a container. I add my own GLSurfaceView to this RelativeLayout by code :

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    setContentView( R.layout.main );
    MyOpenGLSurfaceView view = new MyOpenGLSurfaceView( getApplication() );
    LinearLayout openGLLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.openGLLayout);
    openGLLayout.addView(mView);
}
```

I use this method mainly for confirmation popups or contextual menus. This way I don't have to create my own buttons using openGL.

Answer (score 1):

The typical solution is to draw your 3D scene, then switch to an orthographic projection and paint the HUD still using OpenGL. Placing ordinary components on top of an OpenGL canvas will probably have unpredictable results (they might flicker or just simply be invisible).

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue and i battled it for almost a year now.  I did not use an xml layout, but instead am adding the views in java like so:

```
rel.addView(camPreview, camParams);
rel.addView(glView, glParams);
rel.addView(imageView, imageParams);
```

one suggestion that i got was to add a z index param to the addView calls like so:

```
rel.addView(camPreview, 0, camParams);
rel.addView(glView, 1, glParams);
rel.addView(imageView, 2, imageParams);
```

but that didn't work either..

i even tried switching to xml layout but still not what i wanted

in the end the solution was:

```
glView.setZOrderMediaOverlay(true);
rel.addView(camPreview, camParams);
rel.addView(glView, glParams);
rel.addView(imageView, imageParams);
```

**NOTE:  setZOrderMediaOverlay(true) needs to be called before you actually add the view**

try that and let me know if that works for you.